# Generate Surface with CubeFile from Gaussian in VMD or other free programm

Tags: computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, density-functional-theory

I asked a question before, about how to save a mapped surface from GaussView. I don't get an answer, so I get much deeper in my internet research about it again.

Now I want to try to create a mapped surface of the electronic potential with VMD. So I found out, that I must create the cubefile before with gaussian. After that I import my cube file to VMD.
I followed multiple advises and introductions on the internet, but none of them worked for me.

I tried it also on my own, but this works not as well. 
What musst I do on VMD or even when I create my cubefile on gaussian? Got somebody a proper link for me or can give me an advise? My target is to create a figure which can be used for publishing a thesis.

Thanks, Andrea!

If you need some files or something just let me know!

Comment: I believe [this guide](http://glab.cchem.berkeley.edu/mgcf/faqs/vmd_orbitals.html) answers your question. [Archived version](http://archive.today/pItpD) just in case it goes offline in the future.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer what you want? Do you want to map the electrostatic potential on a isosurface of another property? Something like this: https://people.chem.ucsb.edu/kahn/kalju/chem162/public/smallmol_visual_elpot.html